# How to generate all possible combination of words (Python)

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

Let's assume that we have 6 strings:

`Input: ["Love", "Is", "What", "I", "Care", "About"]`

Then what can I do to find all combination of words for the output to be like:

Love Is What I Care About

Love Is What I About Care

About Care I What Is Love

And so on with no repetition

---

I'm new to this, hope you guys can help me.

Many Thanksss

Comment: Also reminder to others to not downvote well formatted duplicates. Flags are there for a reason

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> inputs = ["Love", "Is", "What", "I", "Care", "About"]
>>> list(itertools.permutations(inputs, len(inputs)))
```

Comment: Please do not do the homework for other SO Users. They will not learn anything from it except ask the next homework question here.

Comment: Do not post code only. Add also an explanation